# iexplore.exe stays open after closing Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet-explorer, windows-registry

I sometimes use Internet Explorer 10, and I noticed that once you start Internet Explorer the process

```
iexplore.exe
```

shows up in the Task Manager. This is normal, however this process is not killed if you close Internet Explorer and will keep running until you manually <kbd>End Process</kbd>. Can I change some registry setting to enable sane behavior with this process?

Using
[Turn Windows features on or off](http://sevenforums.com/tutorials/5023-windows-features-turn-off.html) you can turn Internet Explorer off and then back on, but it will only fix the problem temporarily.

Comment: Have you turned off Feeds and Web Slices in Explorer Options under the Content Tab ? This might be keeping your IE open even when you close it.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing with IE 1 1 and AblockPlus. The latter could easily be part of the cause, since that first iexplore.exe process has an AdblockPlusEngine.exe subprocess alongside the usual 32-bit iexplore.exe worker process, but I've noticed another strange symptom: If I open IE again after closing all the original windows, I get a *whole other family* of iexplore.exe processes, rather than the first family getting reused!  (But no second AdblockPlusEngine.exe.)